# Applying an operation to all previously emitted items

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-kotlin

I have a queue of items that will send once the server is reachable:
`val queueHistory: Observable<QueuedItem>`

A QueuedItem is:
`data class QueuedItem(val item: Item, val sent: Boolean = false)`

The queueHistory never completes, it just records when an item is being queued to be sent `onNext(QueuedItem(item1, false)`, and then later records it was sent `onNext(QueuedItem(item1, true)`.

**What I want to do is get a current count of how many unsent items there are.**

The main source of my trouble is due to the list not completing, I was initially thinking of using `collect` but that needs a completed list.

I was playing around with using `scan` with something like
`queueHistory.scan { items: ScannedItems, item -> ScannedItems(arrayOf(*items, item), 0) }`
Where I could keep the current list of items I have encountered so far, but scan wants everything to be the same type.

Another idea I had was

```
queueHistory
            .groupBy { it.item }
            .flatMapSingle { it.toList() }
            .map { it.size % 2 }
```

But toList() needs a finite list.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `#scan` overload, which takes a seed value and a lambda, which takes two parameters (prev, current). The `prev` parameter is of the same type as the seed, the `current` parameter is of the same type as the upstream.

### Example

```
class So65587608 {
    @Test
    fun `65587608`() {
        val producer = PublishSubject.create<QueuedItem>()

        val map = producer.scan(mutableListOf<QueuedItem>(), { list, curr ->
            // when send = true -> remove
            if (curr.sent) {
                list.removeIf { it.item == curr.item }
            } else if (!list.any { it.item == curr.item }) {
                list.add(curr)
            }
            list.toMutableList()
        }).map { list -> list as List<QueuedItem> }

        map.subscribe {
            println(it)
        }

        val test = map.test()

        producer.onNext(QueuedItem("1"))
        producer.onNext(QueuedItem("1", true))
        producer.onNext(QueuedItem("2", true))
        producer.onNext(QueuedItem("3", true))
        producer.onNext(QueuedItem("4"))
        producer.onNext(QueuedItem("5"))
        producer.onNext(QueuedItem("4", true))
    }

    data class QueuedItem(val item: String, val sent: Boolean = false)
}
```

### Output

```
[] // seed value
[QueuedItem(item=1, sent=false)]
[]
[]
[]
[QueuedItem(item=4, sent=false)]
[QueuedItem(item=4, sent=false), QueuedItem(item=5, sent=false)]
[QueuedItem(item=5, sent=false)]
```

### Note

You have to make a copy of the list each #scan iteration or use a immutable list from persistent data collections.

Furthermore this is probably not a good implementation, because the list is unbound, which could take all your memory. If the list is big enough, the linear search might take some time as well, which is probably not good. One should think how the loopup could be done better.

Comment: Thank you so much for the insights! I've also been troubled by the length of the list and was thinking of using some sort of cached subject/producer, once I've shown the user that all the queued items are sent, I no longer need the current queue history.